# navigate to the source code of the running apk and inspect the files

Tags: java, android

I have the source code on my machine and the same builded apk is profiled into the simulator, but I am stuck at the code navigation, though I can get all logs via

`adb logcat *`

but not able to navigate to the html code or to the class files

the same feature that our browser provides after we do the `inspect element` in the context click on any browser, I don't know if this is possible for android applications.

I tried way to navigate to the element's source via appium-tool for the running application in the simulator, but that didn't navigate me to the particular class files. that shows the elements from the web-view, not the class files that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes, it is possible to navigate to the code of an Android application, but it's not as straightforward as it is in a web browser. There are a few different ways to do it, but the most common way is to use a tool called Android Debug Bridge (ADB).

ADB is a command-line tool that allows you to communicate with an Android device or emulator. One of the things that ADB can do is list the classes that are currently loaded in an Android application. To do this, you can use the following command:

   adb shell dumpsys | grep classes

This will output a list of all the classes that are currently loaded in the application. You can then use this list to navigate to the source code for the class that you're interested in.
```

Comment: does it also has the capability to navigate to the particular method

Comment: No, ADB itself does not have the capability to navigate to a particular method in the source code of an Android application. ADB is primarily a command-line tool used for various Android device and emulator operations.

Comment: For code navigation, you would typically use an  IDE like Android Studio.  You can use keyboard shortcuts: In Android Studio, you can use "Ctrl + B" (Windows/Linux) or "Cmd + B" (macOS) to navigate to the declaration of a class, method, or variable.